# How Bitcoin node discovery work?

Tags: nodes, seed

When you install Bitcoin client, how does it discover the nodes to get a copy of the blockchain?
Are their seed nodes ? Are they vulnérables? SPOF ?

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! What is SPOF?

Comment: single point of failure

Comment: All the seed nodes are independent of each other AFAIK, if DNS is hacked we likely have bigger problems.

Answer (score 1):

There are several hard-coded DNS seeds, which work AFAIK as a DNS round-robin to provide connection to several random nodes.

Once initially connected to nodes, peer discovery is automatic and your node could easily learn about the entire network through just a few connected nodes.

There is a slight chance that a malicious ISP could hijack DNS or for that matter, all Bitcoin traffic, either preventing peer discovery or alternatively providing false or limited results. [This has already been asked elsewhere](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/70263/what-happens-if-an-isp-isolate-a-portion-of-nodes/71975#71975). Provided you are able to connect to just a few well-connected nodes on main-net everything will work as expected.