# Tor on Mac ? Bitcoin Core v0.20

Tags: mac, tor

I'd like to know hot to put my BT Core behind Tor **ON A MAC**. 
I've searched everywhere but could't find how. I always find Win or Linux instructions but nothing on the Mac side.
Only "Tor for Mac" I was able to find was a Tor Browser, but i guess it's not the same. 
Anyone has a proper link with some steps to follow? I am quite a noob.
I've been running this node for years and sometimes when I raise this question I get the answer "don't worry , there's nothing wrong even if your IP is public" but I somehow feel more secure knowing I can contribute to the network without exposing my IP 24/7 ...

Comment: Did you check https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/70069/how-can-i-setup-bitcoin-to-be-anonymous-with-tor and https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-osx.html.en?